# External SD card gets corrupted on removal

Tags: android, usb-drive

I'm using the [libaums](https://github.com/magnusja/libaums) library (version 0.7.0) for reading SD cards via a USB card reader.

The issue I'm having is that if I don't go into the phone storage options and choose to unmount the SD card before removing it, it always becomes corrupted when I take it out, even if I don't actually write anything to it (Windows complains about it when inserted in a Windows machine). Calling `device.init()` is enough to trigger the problem.

I wonder if I'm perhaps using the library incorrectly or if nothing else, there is a way to unmount the USB card reader automatically from my app once I'm finished with it? As I understand it calling `device.close()` SHOULD be enough to flush data and secure the card for removal.

This is the code I'm using for accessing the card:

```
private class FindDevicesTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, String> {
    private WeakReference<Context> mContext;

    FindDevicesTask (Context context){
        mContext = new WeakReference<>(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Integer... dummy) {
        Context ctx = mContext.get();
        if (ctx == null)
            return null;  // Context expired

        UsbMassStorageDevice[] devices = UsbMassStorageDevice.getMassStorageDevices(ctx);
        for (final UsbMassStorageDevice device : devices) {

            // If we don't have permission, request it and leave this function (if we get
            // permission the function will be called again)
            if (!mUsbManager.hasPermission(device.getUsbDevice())) {
                mUsbManager.requestPermission(device.getUsbDevice(), mPermissionIntent);
                return null;
            }

            try {
                device.init();

                // Do work

            } catch (IOException e) {
                return e.getMessage();
            } finally {
                device.close();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (result == null || result.isEmpty())
            return;

        Context ctx = mContext.get();
        if (ctx != null)
            displayString(result, "USB connection error", ctx);
    }

};
```

Started by calling `new FindDevicesTask(context).execute();`

Comment: Hey there, this is weird. Does this also happen if you do not call device.close()? Nothing should be written if you do not change anything ...
Can you maybe add some debug statements to the write command in the block device to make sure that there are no writes. Without writing to the device this behavior is very odd...

Comment: When I omit device.close() and don't do anything other than calling device.init() there are no problems as you suspected. I added breakpoints to the write function in ByteBlockDevice, ScsiBlockDevice and FileBlockDeviceDriver. None of them triggered when device.close() was called.

Comment: Yeah that is what I would have thought. There is no write to the device happening. So maybe just use it without device.close() for now as this only releases some Android specific USB host resources. On file system level as long as you call flush or close when done writing files everything should be transferred to the device.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to report that this issue was not with the libaums library but rather Android itself. My device automatically configures SD cards it sees to work with Android (it adds some system folders and files). When this happens it does something that makes Windows not like the SD card anymore, although it's by no means corrupt (Windows can read it no problem).